# Is it possible to search for images and get the result on my own website using an API?

Tags: json, image, api, flickr

I wonder if we can get the results in the form of images by search via a search box?

Have searched around a bit and Flickr seems to have something similar but wonder if there are other options?

(new to API... :) )

Answer (score 1):

Try [Pixabay](http://www.pixabay.com), it's a newly website for free and high quality images. They have also an [API](http://pixabay.com/api/docs/) for searching and retrieving public domain images.